# Is there a way to have a colorbar for a contour plot being continous instead of discret using fig.colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I managed to plot a colorbar for a contourplot, but the colors are displayed as discete stripes instead of a continous spectrum. The colorbar is based on the data the contourplot, which I do not want to be displayed as continous.

I have six contour-plots as subplots in one figure. The value scale for all is from 0 to 1. At the right side, the colorbar is attached to two axes of the subplots (ax3, ax6) based on the data from one of the subplots:

`Z = ax6.contour(data_5["z"], extent=[0*5, 10*5, 0*5, 7*5],levels=20)`

`cbar = fig.colorbar(Z, ax=[ax3,ax6], shrink=0.8, pad=0.01, aspect=10)`

`fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)`

Is there a parameter I can add to have the colors in the colorbar be displayed as continuum or another way to achieve this?

Comment: `fig.colorbar(plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=Z.norm, cmap=Z.cmap), ticks=Z.levels)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). In this case, either ask for it to be reopened, such that you can add your answer here, or post your answer at either of the duplicate posts.